# Introducing github-markdown-css in Vue3 How to manually toggle dark mode css

Tags: css, vue.js, vite

I use Vue3 and github-markdown-css in my project.

The `github-markdown.css` is based `prefers-color-scheme`, so I cannot do anything.

And it provides `github-markdown-light.css` and `github-markdown-dark.css`.
I had searched and tried many ways to change the imported CSS file, but they all donot work.

Or is we really can do this in Vue?

Are there some ways to slove this problems.